# Match Sections of SQL Connection String with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have written a regex to match section of an SQL Connection string. In the first spec, the Initial Catalog etc. were forced not to contain special characters. So I had

```
string strConn = "Data Source=VAIOE;Initial Catalog=SomeTextOnlyCatname;Integrated 
    Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=0;";
Regex databaseNameRegex =
    new Regex(@"(?i)\b(Initial\sCatalog|Database)\b\s?=\s?(\w+\s*)*;?");
```

Now, I need to match sections which could have names with symbols, punctuation etc. For example

```
string strConn = "Data Source=VAIOE;Initial Catalog=N3wC@t@l0gName*6Symbols;Integrated 
    Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=0;";
```

where I want to return `Initial Catalog=N3wC@t@l0gName*6Symbols`.

I have tried

```
Regex databaseNameRegex =
    new Regex(@"(?i)\b(Initial\sCatalog|Database)\b\s?=\s?(\w+\p{P}*\p{M}*\p{Z}*\s*)*;?");
```

but this fails, due to the presence of semi-colons in the connection string. What is the best regex to deal with this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you use [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) to parse the connection string for you and avoid the RegEx?  If you just need the data base name, the following should work:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
Console.WriteLine(conn.Database);
```

**EDIT**

A better way to do this was provided by Allon Guralnek - Thanks!

Use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) for this - it will extract any information you need.

```
var connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(strConn);
Console.WriteLine(connBuilder.InitialCatalog);
```

Comment: I'd actually use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class, which will provide access to all the key-value pairs inside a connection string. It will also let you construct a connection string from key-value pairs. So to get the Initial Catalog you can use `new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(myConnectionString).InitialCatalog`.

Comment: This is a great idea. I think I will use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilderClass`.

Comment: Well then, that is convenient!