# Extracting info from SQLite connection string

Tags: regex, sqlite, connection-string

A typical connection string for SQLite would be something like:

```
Data Source=test.db;Version=3;
```

I have seen similar questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299860/match-sections-of-sql-connection-string-with-regex)) on parsing connection string and they generally end up saying to use SqlConnectionStringBuilder (I'm obviously on .Net). This seems to be a great option for most strings, but it will not work for SQLite. It throw an exception "Keyword not supported:'version'".

I am thinking Regex may be the only option here, but does anyone know if there are there any other options? I'd love to get the Regex expression for getting Data Source as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though I would answer my own question. The option I ended up using was DbConnectionStringBuilder. It is the base class for SqlConnectionStringBuilder (duh!). So, I can do this:

```
DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
string filePath = ((string)builder["Data Source"]).Trim();
```